# Printing lists in columns from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a small program where a user enters a name and a present they would give to someone. This data is then saved in the format `["name","present"]` and then a new line for new inputs in a text file.

When I print it, it appears like this.

```
["bob","car"]
["charlie","mansion"]
```

Which is to be expected. 
I want to print it in columns so it prints like this.

```
bob        car
charlie    mansion
```

I know how to remove `[],'` so it displays properly but don't know how to print in columns.

I did research and found methods like `zip` but they print the text like this.

```
bob     charlie
car     mansion
```

Which isn't the order I want it in.

Comment: This should point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309255/how-to-pad-a-string-to-a-fixed-length-with-spaces-in-python

Comment: It most definitely did. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to determine the longest name in your data to use its lenght to format your data:

```
data = [
    ["bob", "car"],
    ["charlie", "mansion"]
]

n = max(len(item[0]) for item in data) + 5  # We add 5 more spaces between columns

for item in data:
    print('{:<{n}} {}'.format(*item, n=n))
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be more pythonic ways but here's my solution

```
In [58]: a = ["bob","car"]

In [59]: b = ["charlie","mansion"]

In [60]: cc = [a,b]

In [61]: for item in cc:
 ...:         print("{:<7} {:<7}".format(item[0],''.join(map(str,item[1:]))))

bob     car
charlie mansion
```