# How to print a array with numbered columns and rows nicely (in python)?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist, printf

Currently strugging with nicely printing a array of "O"'s, where the columns and rows should be numbered.

So I have a array which is just a nxn-matrix full of the string "O". Now I tried using the following method:

```
    def __repr__(self) :
        Matrix  = self.Spielstand           #this is just the mentioned array of length n:
        Ausgabe = "   "
        for j in range(len(Matrix[0])):
            Ausgabe += str(j + 1) + " "    

        Ausgabe += "\n"

        for i in range(len(Matrix)):
            Ausgabe += str(i + 1) + "  "
            for j in range(len(Matrix[i])):
                Ausgabe += str(Matrix[i][j])
                Ausgabe += " "
            Ausgabe += "\n"
        return Ausgabe
```

Which works perfectly fine printing something like:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1  O O O O O O O O
2  O O O O O O O O
3  O O O O O O O O
4  O O O O O O O O
5  O O O O O O O O
6  O O O O O O O O
7  O O O O O O O O
8  O O O O O O O O
```

However when my n gets bigger than 9, things get kind of weird:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1  O O O O O O O O O O
2  O O O O O O O O O O
3  O O O O O O O O O O
4  O O O O O O O O O O
5  O O O O O O O O O O
6  O O O O O O O O O O
7  O O O O O O O O O O
8  O O O O O O O O O O
9  O O O O O O O O O O
10  O O O O O O O O O O
```

Is there a simple and nice way (preferably without using external libraries) to print the array nicely even if my n is double or even triple digit? I think using f-Strings and something going from center should work, but I have no clue how to implement it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you just want to figure out the maximum number of digits, then pad with spaces, as discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20309255/6394617)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate margin size by counting the length of the number converted to string.

```py
Margin = len(str(len(Matrix)))
```

```
Martix -> (array of 12 "O")
len(Martix) -> 12
str(12) -> "12"
len("12") -> 2
```

I have created demo, with a solution to your problem:

```py
def generateMatrix(n):
    return [["O"] * n] * n

def draw(n):
    Matrix = generateMatrix(n)
    Margin = len(str(len(Matrix)))
    Ausgabe = " " * (Margin + 1)
    for j in range(len(Matrix[0])):
        Ausgabe += str(j + 1) + " " * (Margin - len(str(j+1)) + 1)
    Ausgabe += "\n"
    for i in range(len(Matrix)):
        Ausgabe += str(i + 1) + " " * (Margin - len(str(i+1)) + 1)
        for j in range(len(Matrix[i])):
            Ausgabe += str(Matrix[i][j])
            Ausgabe += " " * Margin
        Ausgabe += "\n"
    return Ausgabe

print(draw(12))
```

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 
1  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
2  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
3  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
4  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
5  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
6  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
7  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
8  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
9  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
10 O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
11 O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  
12 O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something with f strings and then force every value to be displayed to the same width.

```
f'{value:{width}.{precision}}'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50340297/9050785